# Rails: Where to define constants with Classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a constant that is based on classes I define in lib:

```
ALL_DEMOGRAPHICS = [Demographic::Gender,
                    Demographic::Age]
```

I tried putting them in config/initializers, but they would get cached and not update even when I saved a new version of the class/file.

Where should I put this constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried putting them in config/initializers, but they would get cached and not update even when I saved a new version of the class/file.

You could define them in a module. Create a file called `global_constants.rb` in your models directory and add constants there:

*app/models/global_constants.rb*

```
module GlobalConstants
  ALL_DEMOGRAPHICS = [Demographic::Gender, Demographic::Age]
end
```

Then you can use the constants like so:

```
GlobalConstants::ALL_DEMOGRAPHICS
```

If you keep the module in lib folder, then make sure you have added lib to autoload:

*config/application.rb*

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: Would there be another directory I could put it in outside of `app/`?

Comment: app/models/global_constants.rb

Comment: You could put it in the /lib directory.  Just be sure you've rails configured to load the files under this directory.